# Microsoft Edge always open new tab instead of new window

Tags: microsoft-edge

Since last week, when I right click on Edge taskbar tab to open new tab or new window, it opens a new tab always, instead of opening a different window

This is how it looks.

[image: Edge]

I checked out all options, but didn't find any such customization. I tried to un-install and re-install the Edge browser, it worked for a while, but once the system restarted, it started same behavior again!

Any idea, how could I change that to open new window when clicking on 'Microsoft Edge' instead of opening a new tab in an existing window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, I assume that there might be some malicious software hijacking your Edge browser. It locks the homepage of Edge and tampers the shortcut of "Microsoft Edge".

The right behavior of clicking on "Microsoft Edge" should be opening a new window. But I can reproduce your issue with the steps below:

1. Right click Edge icon on taskbar.
2. Right click **Microsoft Edge** then click **Properties**.
3. In the **Microsoft Edge Properties** window, add a webpage url after **Target** value.

[image][image]

4. Click **Apply**, **OK** to save the changes.
5. Click **Microsoft Edge** in taskbar Edge right click menu, it will open the webpage url as a new tab in an existing window.

You can refer to my steps above to check your Edge Target value in Microsoft Edge Properties. **Please make sure there's only the path of Edge exe in the Target value.** The right value of Target should be like this (your path might be different with mine, below is just an example of mine):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"
```

If there's anything else, it's very likely that a malicious software tampers it. Then you should check your computer thoroughly to remove any malicious software and virus.

Comment: Thanks for the great tip, this morning, it is working as expected, but I will now keep an eye on it to see if there is anything changing the Target

Comment: You're welcome. You can come back any time if you have any updates about the issue.